# find the dimension of Rng(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble finding the $\dim R(T)$, as to determine rank-nullity theorem and to determine of a given linear transformation is onto.

For instance, how would I find the $\dim R(T)$ for the following matrix (where $T(x)=Ax$):

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2\\
        -2 & -2\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I row reduced it and find the $R(T) = \{ (1,-2) \}$ or simple the colspace of T. But what is the dimension of the range? I thought it was the number of components in the vector, but I have been told the $\dim R(T)$, for this problem, is $1$. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find the dimension of the range of $T(x)=Ax$, where $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\-2 & -4\end{array}\right].$$ Row-reducing gives you a matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\0 & 0\end{array}\right],$$ which has only one row beginning with a non-$0$ entry. That means that the dimension of the range of $T$ is $1$. If your row reduction got you to a matrix of the form $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & *\\0 & 1\end{array}\right],$$ then you've got *two* rows beginning with a non-$0$ entry, and so the dimension of the range of $T$ in that case would be $2$.

---

Let's look at it another way. The range of $T$ will be spanned by $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is any basis for the space that $T$ is acting on. Let's go ahead and take the standard ordered basis, so the range of $T$ is spanned by $T(e_1)=[1,-2]^t$ and $T(e_2)=[2,-4]^t$. Since $T(e_2)=2T(e_1)$, then $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ are not linearly independent. Tossing one of them out gives us a basis for the range of $T$. For example, then, $\bigl\{[1,-2]^t\bigr\}$ is a basis for the range of $T$. This has only one vector in it, so the range of $T$ has dimension $1$.